# How to back a generic data structure with an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, data-structures

I have a good understanding of data structures and can happily implement them in C++ without issue; I get a little tripped up in Java though due to the generic implementation constraints.

Specifically, I get confused when I'm trying to create a data structure backed by an array.  I know, for example, that I cannot do this:

```
public class HashTable<T> {
    private T[] table;    
    public HashTable() {
        table = new T[10]; //Type param T cannot be instantiated directly.
    }
}
```

I also know that if I back my generic array list with an object array, I'm going to have to suppress a number of "unchecked cast" warnings which seems of ill form.

What is the best way to create an array-based data structure in Java?  Is there some trick that can be used to do it in a cleaner manner than just creating a straight object array and dealing with the messy casting?

Comment: That's a good duplicate flag admittedly; that question answers my issue perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a raw array, use an `ArrayList<T>`.  It's basically a generic wrapper around an array, with a bunch of additional features.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Sorry, I think you misunderstood me a little :).  I'm asking how you would implement something like array list in the first place.  More for theoretical/interview knowledge than for practical use. Array list itself must have addressed this issue; I'm just curious what the best way ended up being.